# No remaining space in Teradata Database

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I created a database of storage 18 gb using:

```
CREATE DATABASE demo FROM DBC
AS
PERM = 18000000000, -- 18GB
SPOOL = 15000000000; -- 15GB
NO FALLBACK
NO BEFORE JOURNAL
NO AFTER JOURNAL;
```

I need to load data from a *csv* file of size **10 gb** into this database and I'm using the **Tdload** utility.

The command I'm using is:

```
tdload -h hostid -u user -p password -t demo_table -f demofile.csv  
--TargetWorkingDatabase demo --TargetErrorLimit 100 jobid
```

I'm getting `No Space remaining in the database` message after a while, after running this command.

How to resolve this?

**Note**: The database has only 1 table which is empty, in which I'm trying to load data.

Comment: Things to check: Is the target table Fallback? See SHOW TABLE. Is the Primary Index skewed? See dbc.TableSizeV

Comment: The table is Fallback.
The CurrentPerm value is unevenly distributed.

Comment: Try to add 3GB to the perm database size

Comment: You need to assign the (max currentperm per AMP) * (number of AMPs) to the database. Unless your system has mandatory Fallback you might try to switch it off. Depending on your system you might switch on Block Level Compression for this table.